# In Avengers Endgame how does Colonel Rhodes Get a working suit after the Avengers tower is attacked

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

I was again watching the good old *Endgame* and noticed this, when the Avengers facility is struck by Thanos's missiles, Rhodes is found struggling to move even in his War-Machine suit to save Rocket and has to get out of this suit to help him.

But when the portals are opening and Ant-Man becomes big and helps Hulk, Rocket and Rhodes out of debris, Rhodes has a brand new suit (or maybe just the old one).

How is this possible?

> [Rhodes having problem with the suit (skip to 48 sec)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5arw6e6v6Po)

> [Rhodes having a perfectly fine suit (skip to 2:05 min)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fP2w_UAK6B4)

Comment: Good question, asked before but good question.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot how can i find duplicates effectively, it's gonna save me some time?

Comment: @arjun - the site has a pretty decent search facility. If you search for war machine, it's one of the only questions that comes up

Comment: @Arjun just use tags and keywords. I know of most mainly because I’ve seen them before though.